# Is there strict type check in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm codding some library with TypeScript, and I want to protect calls my methods from incorrect meaning data. Let's see next example:

```js
type BookId = number;
type AuthorId = number;

BooksService.getById(bookId: BookId): Book {
    // ...
};

let authorId: AuthorId;

// I need to get some type error in next lene, because getById() expect receive BookId, not AuthorId:
book = BooksService.getById(authorId);
```

Is it possible to get this error? How to upgrade my example to get it?

Comment: A number is a number. How is a compiler supposed to understand the difference just by the name of a variable?